# C# MVC AngularJS: Controller Methods invoked, but not receiving values from the $http.post() method

Tags: c#, arrays, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have an Angular app that invokes a c#mvc method:

AngularJS:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'panelists': $scope.arr, 'webId': $scope.webinarId });

    //Call the services
    $http.post('/Home/CreatePanelists', JSON.stringify(data))
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.msg = 'Post Data Submitted Successfully!';
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.msg = 'Service not Exists';
        });
```

Contents of data:

```
{"panelists":[{"name":"ali","email":"ali@email.com"},{"name":"tom","email":"tom@email.com"},{"name":"arthur","email":"arthur@email.com"}],"webId":94395753244}
```

Added the following Files:

*/Models/Home/Panelist.cs*

```
public class Panelist
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

*/Models/Home/Parameters.cs*

```
public class Parameters
{
    public IList<Panelist> panelists { get; set; }
    public string webId { get; set; }

}
```

Updated the Controller:

/Controllers/HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult CreatePanelists(Parameters data)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.webId);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.panelists);

     return new EmptyResult();
}
```

By the time when the debugger enters the CreatePanelists method, I added a watch on data, and both, panelists, and webId are null.

I don't understand where the problem resides. When I debug the AngularJS code in Chrome, and get to the step in which the post request is made, I see that the variable data, does have the array of objects with values (as shown above).

Why is the MVC Controller method CreatePanelist is not seeing these values?

If somebody have an idea and would not mind offering it, that would be nice.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from calling `JSON.stringify` twice. You are already stringifying it when setting the variable `data`, don't do it a second time in your `post`.